# snmp concatenation (part of an array output with oid)

Tags: javascript, node.js, snmp, net-snmp, node-red

I am working on SNMP in node red.

I want to see the callActiveCallState, so I am doing snmp table on this oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.3.1 to see the output of "row index".

I am writing a function that concatenate the rowIndex from the snmp table's output with this oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.3.1.1.9.

I am doing that because I need the ouput of this oid "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.3.1.1.9.row index".

So the function that I am writing is:

```
msg.oid = "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.3.1.1.9";
msg.oid += "."+ msg.payload[0]; 
return msg;
```

but I have a problem about `payload[0]`.

any idea? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should provide more information. What is `msg.payload`? Can you print it with `console.log(msg.payload)` before the code you show? That way you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

here is the output of the `snmp` table (this is the `msg.payload`) : it returns an object.

```
{ "topic": "", "payload": { "130277300.1": { "3": [ 53, 50, 56 ], "4": [], "5": 1, "6": 26, "7": 0, "8": 130278301, "9": 4, "10": 2, "11": 0, "12": 2, "13": 2783, "14": 445280, "15": 2781, "16": 444960 }, "130277870.1": { "3": [ 51, 48, 51, 48, 48, 51, 51, 48, 57, 50, 55, 48 ], "4": [], "5": 3030, "6": 54, "7": 4, "8": 130278300, "9": 4, "10": 1, "11": 0, "12": 2, "13": 2781, "14": 467208, "15": 2784, "16": 445440 } }, "_msgid": "50c956bf.af36a8", "oid": "1.3.6.1.2.1.10.21.1.3.1" }
```

I need to extract from this output the 2 row indexed: `130277300.1 and 130277870.1` and concatenate it with the oid

Comment: payload is an object and not an array. It's accessed with keys like that: `msg.payload['130277300.1']` and it equals `{ "3": ...etc }`. So you need to know 130277300.1 or access blindly the first key.

Comment: Ive found the answer. Thanks all

Comment: @aline In future please edit your original question to add more information, do not add data as answers